# How to delete a listener in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I make a [copy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178222/how-to-delete-a-listener-in-openlayers-3) of my question here at stackoverflow, because at gis.stackexchange all my questions do not attract any attention - many times I could not get an answer to simple questions there. So, my question now is how to delete a listener defined this way:

```
map.getViewport().addEventListener('click', function (e){
   console.log("clicked");      
});
```

Comment: if you use getViewport() it will return a HTMLElement which has nothing to do with openlayers. 
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

Comment: openlayers listener adding and removing is described at http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Object.html, btw.

Comment: If you want to register a click on the map to, let's say, know the coordinate clicked, then you definitively should use the ol3 native map browser events as the event object would contain that information.

Comment: @Alexandre Dubé. Thanks! Now I'm using `map.on`

Comment: Can you go back and accept @Alexandre Dubé answer, as it seems to be the most helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OL3 emmits its own kind of events you could use instead and, to answer your original question, gives an easy and quick way to unregister them.

Look at this example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/vector-layer.html

More specifically, at these lines:

```
  map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.dragging) {
      return;
    }
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
    displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
  });

  map.on('click', function(evt) {
    displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
  });
```

The `ol.Map` object has a `on` method you can use to register event listeners on the ol3 map browser events.  It's best to use those events instead of standard browser events.  See the list of all map browser events here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html

To **unregister**, you can:

a) use the `un` method, but make sure you to give **the same callback method** as 2nd argument.  In other words:

```
  var callback = function(evt) {
    displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
  };
  map.on('click', callback);
  map.un('click', callback);
```

b) an other way is to use the `ol.Observable.unByKey` method, which I like a lot.  When calling `on` or `once`, **it returns a key** that references the event.  You can then use that key to unlisten your event:

```
  var key = map.on('click', function(evt) {
    displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
  });
  ol.Observable.unByKey(key);
```

I find b) to be more friendly as you can register a bunch of event listeners and put all the keys inside an array.  When you want to unregister them all, loop in the array and call the unByKey method, then empty the array.  It generates less code that way than having to unregister all events manually.

Answer (score 1):

to remove first thing to do is to declare an external function attached to the click 
and then remove it with `removeEventListener`

like this

```
function myFunction(event){
   //some stuff 
   console.log("clicked");   
}

map.getViewport().addEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

and then remove it by

```
map.getViewport().removeEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

that's all

Here is a snippet

```js
function myfunction(e) {
  alert("event click");
}


document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click",myfunction);



document.getElementById("mybtn2").addEventListener("click",function(e){
   document.getElementById("mybtn").removeEventListener("click",myfunction);
});
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">btn</button><br/>
<button id="mybtn2" >remove btn click</button>
```