# Mousedown / Mouseup event in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I need to detect mousedown and mouseup events and get their coordinates on an Openlayers 3 map, but it doesn't seem to work at all, and I can't find anything about this in the documentation.

```
map.on('click', function(ev){ console.log(ev.coordinate);} );
```

works just fine, and gets the correct position, but when I replace the "click" with "mousedown" it doesn't work anymore (I get no error, just nothing happens).

Another solution would be to use something like:

```
$(map.getViewport()).bind("mousedown", function(e) { });
```

But I can't seem to get the coordinates anymore with this method. I've found map.getEventPixel(e), is there any way to convert this to actual coordinates on the map?

LE: what I actually need is to get the click duration (like when somebody is holding the mouse down for several seconds), so if there is a way to do this without mousedown/mouseup, I'll take any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenLayers `ol.Map` object contains events, such as `click` and `singleclick`, which can be listened to using the `on` method. See the list here (look for the 'Events'): http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html

See an example of use: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/popup.html and a snippet (see that the `evt` parameter contains the `coordinate` you're looking for:

```
  /**
   * Add a click handler to the map to render the popup.
   */
  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
    var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(
        coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));

    content.innerHTML = '<p>You clicked here:</p><code>' + hdms +
        '</code>';
    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
  });
```

You might also be interested to reading how to un-listen those events: [How to delete a listener in OpenLayers 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015174/how-to-delete-a-listener-in-openlayers-3/35015696#35015696)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but I need to detect the mousedown and mouseup events separately (which was supported in openlayers 2, but according to this page http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html doesn't seem to work anymore). So I was wondering if anybody has figured out any way to do this.

Comment: You can try the 'pointerup' and 'pointerdown' events.  See: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.13.1/src/ol/mapbrowserevent.js#L479

Comment: Thank you, pointerup and pointerdown are exactly what I need, and they seem to work fine on both PC and touchscreens. Could you add this as a separate answer, so I can mark the question as answered?